# I have a trademark for a domain but another party registered a similar one using private registration

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-squatting

I have a business and someone created a new domain name and just added an "s" to the end of that domain name, for which I have a trademark. Now those search results are ranking above mine on Google and affecting my business.

I want to send this person a cease and desist letter, but the owner of the domain has hidden their details with Google Domains. What can I do?

Comment: Unless your domain is a registered trade mark there is nothing you can do about it.  You can try complaining to the hosting company, but I doubt you will get far unless you have the TM.

Comment: Yes I have a trademark to the name.

Comment: You should contact an attorney that specializes in Trademark law. They'll be able to send a cease and desist letter to the proxy contact information in the WHOIS record, which will get forwarded to the registrant. They'll also file a [UDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy) based on _bad faith_, an attempt to circumvent traffic to your site, and infringement of your mark. I'd strongly advise against trying to do this yourself since UDRP's can be quite involved, and a cease and desist letter won't have any weight otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I get how much this irritates you.

Is the offender's website in direct competition with yours? Or is he selling something else?  Take a look at [this article](https://www.trademarknow.com/blog/can-internet-search-results-cause-trademark-infringement)... Hiring an attorney to send the Cease & Desist will cost $200+/-, but it will have more weight than one you write yourself.

As for the contact information... certainly there is some way to contact the people running the website. Even if it's a form, you can still copy&paste the letter and send it to them. Or use their form to get better contact information. ("hey, do you have an email or street address?")